# Get row data failed, error of Cannot create property 'guid' on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables. I got error of `Cannot create property 'guid' on string` when I tried to retrieve the row data.

http://jsfiddle.net/rqx14xep

```
var employersTable = $('#employersTable').DataTable();

$('#add').click(function() {
  addRow($('.username').val(), $('.phone').val());
});

$('body').on('click', '#employersTable tr', retrieveRow(this));

function addRow(username, phone) {
  employersTable.row.add([
    '<td>' + username + '</td>',
    '<td>' + phone + '</td>',
  ]).draw();
}

function retrieveRow(e) {
  alert('fire')
  tr = e.target;

  row = employersTable.row(tr);

  detail_data = row.data();
  $("#result").empty().html(detail_data[0] + " " + detail_data[1])
}
```

One more strange thing is my function retrieveRow fire on init, why? I put the function within a click event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your main problem is this line :

```
$('body').on('click', '#employersTable tr', retrieveRow(this));
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This actually *executes* `retrieveRow()` right away. When you reference to a function variable in a `on()` event handler, reference to it as it was a variable :

```
$('body').on('click', '#employersTable tr', retrieveRow);
```

---

You have a different problem in `retrieveRow()` :

```
tr = e.target;
```

`e.target` is not necessarily a `<tr>`, it is most likely the `<td>` you clicked on. The event handler is targeting `#employersTable tr` so `this` contain the reference to the `<tr>` :

```
tr = $(this)
```

is the correct, more safe is

```
tr = $(e.target).closest('tr')
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nkaq816f/**

Comment: why e.target is not tr here? I don't get it. I thought e.target is equavalent to $(this)?

Comment: No, you _are_ actually clicking on the `<td>`'s, but the event is delegated to your `#employersTable tr` handler. If you had `<span>`'s inside your `<td>`'s then those would be the target and so on. Look for yourself, try console out `e.target` in `retrieveRow()`.

Comment: are you good with datatable? if I have classes on my row and they are at page 2 and so on, how do I count that? I can't do each and hasClass using jquery for sure.

Comment: hey @AliciaBrandon, always go through the API! You can iterate over all `rows()` (also the hidden ones) simply by `tables.rows().each()` / `for (var i=0; i<table.rows().length;i++) {`  and similar - there is a [**every()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every())  function you could try out that simplifies the task.  See the code in the link, you can access the hidden DOM `<tr>`  nodes (page #2 etc) by `this.nodes().to$().hasClass()`  in the inner loop in the example..